# Column order change when groupby and agg is on the same column

Tags: pandas

After group by operation, sum and count in the same column, the result sometimes changes the order of the calculated columns. How can I keep the order of calculation and rename the column names?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(product_data)

df = df[df[15] < 1].groupby([7, 8, 10] , as_index=False).agg({11:'sum', 12:{'sum','count'}})
```

OUTPUT 1:

```
7  8     10     11           12  
               sum         count   sum 

P1  PD1  KG  14160.68       39  626.75
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
7  8     10     11           12  
               sum        sum   count 

P1  PD1  KG  14160.68    626.75   39
```

Sum and Count of the same column change the order...

Comment: please copy and paste an example of your dataframe, don't show images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a set to `agg`, pass a list:

```
df = (df[df[15] < 1].groupby([7, 8, 10] , as_index=False)
         .agg({11: 'sum', 
               12: ['sum','count']            # note the list here
              })
     )
```